# Xamarin Essentials Web Authenticator does not return to my app

Tags: webauthenticator

I have followed the steps mentioned in documentation for Xamarin Essentials Web Authenticator. With my url, the user is shown a login page and the login succeeds. However, after successful login the token information is shown in the browser itself. The control never returns to my app. My App url scheme is correct since I verified that typing that url in a web browser prompts me to launch my app.